# The request to open "reverseBundleId-UITests-Runner" failed. The process did launch, but has since exited or crashed

Tags: xcode, uitest

Please help!

[image]

[image]

This happens every time I try to run UITests on Xcode Simulator running Version 9.2 (9C40b).  I can't find any discussions on this issue.

Comment: Did you find solution? I have same error in CI logs.

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t remember.  But since then, I’ve shifted to using unit tests primarily, due to this and other difficulties.